# Regex match longitude value that more than 18 digit

Tags: php, regex

I want to match longitude value: `-3.6503552000000004` using `preg_match('/^([+\-])?(?:180(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$/', $value)` but seems my regex can't validate if more than 15 digits behind the dot.

Here the test I did that passed:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit\Rules;

use App\Rules\LongitudeRule;
use Tests\TestCase;

class LongitudeRuleTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function pass_when_value_between_min_180_to_plus_180()
    {
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '-180'));
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '+180'));
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '-45'));
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '+45'));
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '0'));
    }

    /** @test */
    public function pass_when_value_between_min_180_to_plus_180_and_float()
    {
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '-180.0'));
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '+180.0'));
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '-45.1'));
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '+45.1'));
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '0.0'));
    }

    /** @test */
    public function pass_when_value_between_min_180_to_plus_180_and_no_plus_assigned()
    {
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '-180'));
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '180.0'));
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '-45.1'));
        $this->assertTrue((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '45'));
    }

    /** @test */
    public function failed_when_value_has_using_comma()
    {
        $this->assertFalse((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '45,1'));
        $this->assertFalse((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', '-45,1'));
    }

    /** @test */
    public function failed_when_value_is_wrong()
    {
        $this->assertFalse((new LongitudeRule)->passes('longitude', 'A'));
    }
}
```

I'm new at regex sorry! So.. I do want to say thanks if someone can help?

Comment: Why use regex? Why not just check it's numeric and between -180 and +180?

Comment: `(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?` can't match 15 digits as it can only match 1 through 6 digits after a dot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Any help?

Comment: Just use `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` to match any 1+ digits

Comment: @Nick There a validation match must use `dot` and not `comma`

Comment: Values with commas in them are not numeric in PHP.

Comment: just increase to {1,16} or use Wiktor advice. Then go to https://regex101.com/ or similar website and invest some time to learning regex.

Comment: Fixed with @WiktorStribiżew solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?` can't match 15 digits as it can only match 1 through 6 digits after a dot. So.. need to increase the limit `(?:\.[0-9]{1,16})?` or remove the limit `(?:\.[0-9]+)?`

Thank you 
[@WiktorStribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) 
[@Rokas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7685948/rokas-lak%c5%a1tauskas)